# BeautifulSoup: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, unicode, syntax-error, special-characters

I am trying to scrape all the dates from this webpage, which are inside a table.
How: using find, specifying the element of the table and its attribute (in blue)
Problem: Syntax error, invalid character identifier when I try to extract the entire table.
Additional relevant info: this site requires a username and password so I am using sessions to persist my credentials.

```
import requests
from getpass import getpass
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

URL = "https://d2l.pima.edu/d2l/lms/dropbox/user/folders_list.d2l?ou=475011&isprv=0"
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ("myusername", "mypass")
s.headers.update({"x-test": "true"}) 

# both "x-test" and "x-test2" are sent
s.get("https://d2l.pima.edu/d2l/lms/dropbox/user/folders_list.d2l?ou=475011&isprv=0", headers={"x-test2": "true"})
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("div", attrs= {"id":"id_content_r_c1"}​)
```

the error is referencing the last line of code: invalid character in identifier
However I triple checked and compared against others' codes that work and am not seeing any differences.

Additionally here is the DOC of my webpage
[image]
[image]

traceback:

```
runfile('/Users/rahelmizrahi/Python/scripts/d2lwebscrape1.py', wdir='/Users/rahelmizrahi/Python/scripts')
  File "/Users/rahelmizrahi/Python/scripts/d2lwebscrape1.py", line 26
    results = soup.find("div", attrs= {"id":"id_content_r_c1"}​)
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: yes, and re my code I modified it slightly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the result of copy/pasting the code - let's look at the failing line

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> s = 'results = soup.find("div", attrs= {"id":"id_content_r_c1"})'
>>> for c in s:print(c, ud.name(c))
... 
r LATIN SMALL LETTER R
e LATIN SMALL LETTER E
s LATIN SMALL LETTER S
u LATIN SMALL LETTER U
l LATIN SMALL LETTER L
t LATIN SMALL LETTER T
s LATIN SMALL LETTER S
  SPACE
= EQUALS SIGN
  SPACE
s LATIN SMALL LETTER S
...
1 DIGIT ONE
" QUOTATION MARK
} RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
 ZERO WIDTH SPACE
) RIGHT PARENTHESIS
```

The second last character, "ZERO WIDTH SPACE", which is invisible,  is the problem.  Either delete it or retype the line of code.

Comment: thanks! that worked. can you explain what your last line of code does, and how to read its output? And how did you tell that "zero width  space" was the problem? what does that mean? what would I research to learn more about this? Thank you for the insight, I really appreciate it!